# How to programmatically hide menu on action bars in Android?

Tags: java, android

This is how I declare my menu on my action bars:

```
public void checkUserType() {
   if (mPrefs.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("mahasiswa")) {
      requestData(String.valueOf(mPrefs.getUserID()));
   } else if (mPrefs.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("dosen")) {
      requestData(String.valueOf(mPrefs.getSelectedUserId()));
      getSupportActionBar().hide();
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.exit).setVisible(false);
   }
```

And I want to hide/remove the menu from the action bar using an if-else (not hiding whole action bar, just the menu). I have tried using "myMenu.findItem(R.id.exit).setVisible(false);" but it occurs error on a null object reference

This is my code:

```
public void checkUserType() {
   if (mPrefs.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("mahasiswa")) {
      requestData(String.valueOf(mPrefs.getUserID()));
   } else if (mPrefs.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("dosen")) {
      requestData(String.valueOf(mPrefs.getSelectedUserId()));
      getSupportActionBar().hide();
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.exit).setVisible(false);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will hide a menu item by id:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate( R.menu.main_menu, menu );

    // hide menu item
    menu.findItem( R.id.menu_item_1 ).setVisible( false );
    return true;
}
```

You can apply the same to:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if( item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_1 ) {
        item.setVisible( false );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here just call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and move your logic to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and change visiblity there.

for example

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}
```

and in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setVisible(condition);
}
```

Comment: he asked in java